# Python, CSV to XLS by merge_all_to_a_book

Tags: python

Simple lines to convert .csv files to .xls files.

They work fine but for some files they don't. Seems like the problem lies in the file names.

```
from pyexcel.cookbook import merge_all_to_a_book
import glob
import os

folder = "C:\\CSV\\"
final_folder = "C:\\XLS\\"

root, dirs, files = os.walk(folder).next()

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".csv"):
            merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob(folder + f), final_folder + f + ".xls")
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\Working Scripts\CSV to xls.py", line 20, in <module>
    merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob(folder + f), final_folder + f + ".xls")
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\cookbook.py", line 148, in merge_all_to_a_book
    merged.save_as(outfilename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\book.py", line 249, in save_as
    return save_book(self, file_name=filename)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources\__init__.py", line 46, in save_book
    return _save_any(source, book)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources\__init__.py", line 50, in _save_any
    source.write_data(instance)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\sources\file_source_output.py", line 58, in write_data
    **self._keywords)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel\renderers\_excel.py", line 25, in render_book_to_file
    save_data(file_name, book.to_dict(), **keywords)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 75, in save_data
    **keywords)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\io.py", line 96, in store_data
    writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\book.py", line 161, in write
    sheet_writer = self.create_sheet(sheet_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_xls\xls.py", line 206, in create_sheet
    return XLSheetWriter(self.work_book, None, name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_io\sheet.py", line 139, in __init__
    self.set_sheet_name(sheet_name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyexcel_xls\xls.py", line 156, in set_sheet_name
    self._native_sheet = self._native_book.add_sheet(name)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\xlwt\Workbook.py", line 368, in add_sheet
    raise Exception("invalid worksheet name %r" % sheetname)
Exception: invalid worksheet name u'product list - week.csv'
[Finished in 0.3s with exit code 1]
```

How to correct them? Thank you.

Comment: Show the full traceback that leads up to `raise Exception`

Comment: @tripleee, thank you. added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suddenly found that it works fine on XLSX but not XLS, i.e. to change the last line from:

```
merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob(folder + f), final_folder + f + ".xls")
```

to:

```
merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob(folder + f), final_folder + f + ".xlsx")
```

The files are all succesfully conververted. only a warning message:

```
C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\openpyxl\workbook\child.py:99: UserWarning: Title is more than 31 characters. Some applications may not be able to read the file
warnings.warn("Title is more than 31 characters. Some applications may not be able to read the file")
```

**Edit:**
the above XLSX converted have some problems when manually opened in Excel, for "Some contents are lost". etc

The actual problem lies in the length of file names. When the original file names are shortened, the code works fine to convert CSV to workable XLS files.

Answer (score 1):

There would be some invalid char in your filename.You can modify code like this:

```
import re
from pyexcel.cookbook import merge_all_to_a_book
import glob
import os

def checkNameValid(name=None):

    if name is None:
        print("name is None!")
        return
    reg = re.compile(r'[\\/:*?"<>|\r\n]+')
    valid_name = reg.findall(name)
    if valid_name:
        for nv in valid_name:
            name = name.replace(nv, "_")
    return name

folder = "C:\\CSV\\"
final_folder = "C:\\XLS\\"

root, dirs, files = os.walk(folder).next()

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for f in files:
        if f.endswith(".csv"):
            merge_all_to_a_book(glob.glob(folder + f), final_folder + checkNameValid(f) + ".xls")
```